# How do I connect to vscode node sveltekit app from different device

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to connect to a sveltekit app running in vscode from a different computer(or any device) by running npm run dev. I ran ipconfig to get my ip address and updated my svelte.config.js to have my ip address:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      // Change 'localhost' to your local IP address
      host: '192.168.X.X', // Your local IP address
      // Specify the port you want to use
      port: 5173,
    }),
    // Other configuration options
  },
};

export default config;
```

On the remote computer I am able to ping my ap address. But when I open http://192.168.X.X:5173 it is not connecting. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have a look at this config: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host

Comment: so I usuall don't even change the config, I just invoke `npm run dev -- --host`

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica that worked. I made the config back to default and ran npm run dev -- --host and I was able to connect from a different device. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pointed out to me by Elvis Adomnica. I changed the svelte.config.js back to what it was by default(in my case I use adapter-node instead of adapter-auto to deploy on an IIS server, also I use vitePreporocess for tailwind)

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    },
    preprocess: vitePreprocess()
};

export default config;
```

I did have to add a new rule to the firewall to allow connection through ports 5173. I added 5173-5175 in case I was running multiple apps.

To add a rule in your firewall open start menu and type "Firewall" and click on "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security"

[image: Windows Firewall]

On the left panel click inbound rules. Right click inbound rules and click new rule. We want to add a rule that opens the port so click on port->next. Select TCP. In the box enter the port numbers you want to allow.
[image: Ports]

Click next. Then select "Allow the connection" -> next. Select which networks you want to allow this rule(I did them all because I may be on any of these types. If you are only developing at home or on a domain you may want to select only the one you use so you ports aren't open on a public network) -> next. Give it a name and a description. You want to give it a meaningful name in case you decide to remove it. I named mine "SvelteKit Ports 5173-5175. Click finish.

After that you are good to go. As Elvis said just run `npm run dev -- --host` and you should be able to access it from a different device. The terminal will tell you the address to connect to.